# Wordpress claiming admin user ID as author for all posts

Tags: wordpress

I am using [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/posting-via-the-front-end-editing-and-deleting/) to create a front-end edit page for my blogs posts. I need to add a check to see if the currently logged in user is the author of the post that's being edited. If they aren't then I will be replacing the form with a message.

The problem is for some reason Wordpress is reporting that the admin user ID is the author for all posts, which means my logic is breaking (or rather it is only working if I log in as the admin). The really odd thing is if I edit the posts through the admin dashboard the author is recorded properly (i.e. it's not listed as 'admin' for all posts).

Help!

Answer (score 0):

The post ID is available through a `$_GET` variable, from the tutorial:

```
if ( $_GET['post'] == $post->ID )
{
    $current_post = $post->ID;
}
```

The author ID also resides in the post object:

```
$author_id = $post->post_author;
```

To compare with the ID of the current user:

```
if( get_current_user_id() == $author_id ){
    // current user is the author of the post
} else {
    // current user is NOT the author of the post
}
```

Comment: Is there any place that I should be adding that logic? If I add it within the have_posts section it fires for every post on the site, if I put it by the form the author_id doesn't get pulled through...?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the current user with the post author with this code,

```
$author = $post->post_author; 

global $current_user;

get_currentuserinfo();

if ($author == $current_user->ID){

echo "You are the author of this post";
}
else
{
echo "You are not the author of this post";
}
```

?>

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that would work if only WP wasn't behaving so oddly. Because it still thinks that all posts are authored by the admin id... That's the real question...

Comment: if you were to go into a post created by an author as an admin and update / save, it will then make the admin the author of the post. I find this something really strange with wordpress and does get a bit annoying...